# How do I control the output of rails 4 datetime_local_field?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using `datetime_local_field` and `jquery-datetimepicker-rails` to get local date and time entry in a form.  The view contains:

```
<%= f.datetime_local_field :start, class: 'datetimepicker' %>
```

Which outputs the time in a format including a 'T' between the date and time, eg. `2014-12-29T14:00:32`.  This isn't recognized by the JavaScript as a valid timestamp, so the date and time are not propagated into the picker, and the current timestamp is used instead.  Is there a way to get this to work? Is there a better way to do this?

I've also tried this with `datetime_field` and get similar results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an ISO8601 date format, which JS's `Date.parse` understands. You should override the `jquery-datetimepicker`'s `Date.parseDate` method as described here: http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#use_other_date_parser

Comment: this appears to require modifying the gem, or just not using the gem at all.  In that case I'll find another solution altogether.

Comment: All the gem does is automate the including of the JS, so you can just put that override code in your jquery 'ready' function: `$( Date.parseDate = function( input, format ){ return Date.parse(input); }; );`

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try, as I've already moved the init out of the gem.  I had hoped this would be a straight forward "rails way" to do this, I'm surprised that it doesn't support the format that rails sends out of the box.

Comment: I had to make some adjustments to your code and have posted an answer with the working code.

Answer (score 1):

@smathy's answer led me in the right direction to get this working, at least as well as it can.  I needed to do some further work to get this running. The override of the Date.parsedate must be done before the init runs and it must return an object of type Date.  This results in the following code:

```
//= require jquery.datetimepicker
Date.parseDate = function( input, format ){return new Date(Date.parse(input));};
jQuery(document).on('ready page:change', function() {
    var datetimefield = jQuery('.datetimepicker');
    datetimefield.datetimepicker({
        format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
        lang: datetimefield.attr('lang') || datetimefield.parents('[lang]').attr('lang')
    });
});
```

The `//=require jquery.datetimepicker/init` has been replaced by the actual init code from the gem and the override has been run before it.

I'm no longer using `f.datetime_local_field`, but just `f.datetime_field` to prevent the timezone being applied twice.

Also this code has problems when used more that once on the same page.  the first time you access the earlier fields, they show the timestamp from the last field.  I'm looking for a better date-time picker, and will report back here if I find one.

**Edit: Jan 18, 2014**

I got this working, using Trent Richardson's jQuery timepicker https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon and the browser-timezone-rails gem.  The times are displayed as a formatted value in a text-field

```
      <%= f.text_field :start_time, value: f.object.start_time.strftime('%F %T'), class: 'datetime' %>
```

in a consistent, but human readable format in local time.  The JS config for the timepicker is:

```
$(document).on("ready page:load", function() {
    $('.datetime').datetimepicker({
         dateFormat: $.datepicker.ISO_8601,
        separator: ' ',
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',
        showSecond: false,
        showMillisec: false,
        showMicrosec: false,
        showTimezone: false,
        pickerTimeFormat: 'hh:mm tt'
    });
});
```

The `on("ready page:load"` is required because of `turbolinks` which doesn't cause ready to be fired.  This code properly supports mulitple datetime fields on the page, but it will need some additional validation.